# Understanding pointers and local scope

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Suppose I have the following functions:

```
char* allocateMemory() 
{
    char str[20] = "Hello world.";
    return str;
}

int* another()
{
    int x = 5;
    return &x;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char* pString = allocateMemory();
    printf("%s\n", pString);

    int* blah = another();
    printf("%d %d \n", blah, *blah);

    return 0;
}
```

The first printf prints random values, because str IS LOCAL SCOPE.

The second printf prints the proper values, with blah = address of blah, *blah = 5

Why is it that local scope only affects allocateMemory which deals with arrays, but not integer?

Why does the first printf (returning char* ) prints random values and is affected by local scope, but not the second one (returning int* )?

Comment: Both give random garbage values -- its just randomness that the random value printed for the second one happens to be `5`

Comment: Try calling `another` first, then `allocateMemory`.

Comment: Mandatory reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both ways of accessing the local variables of a method which goes out of scope is Undefined Behavior. These are some valid ways:

```
char* allocateMemory() 
{
    char* str= malloc(sizeof(char) * 20); //assuming C
    strcpy(str, "Hello World.");
    return str; //Valid 
}

const char* allocateMemory() 
{
    return "Hello world."; //Valid Hello World is in read only location
}

int* another()
{
    int *x = malloc(sizeof(int)); //assuming C
    *x = 5;
    return x; //Valid
}
```

Comment: The second `allocateMemory` must return `char const*` to reflect the fact that it points to *"read only location"* as your comment correctly says! **Compilers don't read comments.**.

Comment: `Compilers don't read comments.` Loool. Makes sense.

Comment: Umm really weird, I ran the code in VS2012 many times, always got the correct returns, which is why I was asking. In general though, the proper way to modify a string for example, is to do allocateMemory(char * blah), and modify blah correct?

Comment: Actually nevermind, you can do what I did, just have to store it on the heap, not on the stack

Answer (score 1):

Change the first function to:

```
char* allocateMemory() 
{
    static char str[20] = "Hello world.";
    return str;
}
```

and see the difference.

And now explanation:

When you return address of local data (variable or array, does not matter - it is AUTOMATIC variables) you have a risk to lose data or make a mess in the memory. It was just a good luck that integer data was correct after the second function call. But if you return address of STATIC variables - no mistakes. Also you can allocate memory from HEAP for data and return address.

Answer (score 1):

```
char str[20] = "Hello world.";
```

`str` is local to function `allocateMemory()` and is no more valid once you exit the function and hence accessing it out of its scope if undefined behavior.

```
int x = 5;
```

The same  applies here also.

You can have your data on heap and return the pointer to it is valid.

```
char *allocatememory()
{
   char *p = malloc(20); /* Now the memory allocated is on heap and it is accessible even after the exit of this function */
   return p; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are both, of course, UB, as the other answerers said. They also gave some good ways to do what you want to do in a proper fashion. But you were asking why *does* this actually happen in your case. To understand it, you need to understand what happens in the stack when you call a function. I'll try to provide a *really* simplified explanation.

When a function is called, a new **stack frame** is created on top of the stack. All the data in the function is put onto the stack frame. So, for the function

```
char* allocateMemory() 
{
    char str[20] = "Hello world.";
    return str;
}
```

The stack frame for `allocateMemory` will contain, besides some other stuff, the 20 elements of the string (char array) `str`.

For this function:

```
int* another()
{
    int x = 5;
    return &x;
}
```

The stack frame for `another` will contain the contents of the variable `x`.

When a function returns, the **stack pointer**, which marks the top of the stack, drops all the way down to where it was before a function invocation. However, the memory is still there on the stack, it doesn't get erased - it is a costy and pointless process. However, there is no longer anything protecting this memory from being overwritten by something: it has been marked "unneeded".

Now, what's the difference between your calls to `printf`? Well, when you call `printf`, it gets its *own stack frame*. It overwrites what was left of the previous called function's stack frame.

In the **first case**, you just pass `pString` to `printf`. Then `printf` overwrites the memory that once was the stack frame of `allocateMemory`, and the memory that was once `str` gets covered with stuff `printf` needs to work with string output, like iteration variables. Then it proceeds to try and get memory pointed to by the pointer you passed to it, `pString`... But it has just overwritten this memory, so it outputs what looks like garbage to you.

In the **second case**, you first got the value of the pointer `blah`, which resides in your local scope. *Then* you dereferenced it with `*blah`. Now comes the fun part: you've done the dereferencing *before* you've called another function which could overwrite the contents of the old stack frame. Which means the memory that was once the variable `x` in the function `another` is sort of still there, and by dereferencing the pointer `blah`, you get the value of `x`. And *then* you pass it to `printf`, but now, it doesn't matter that `printf` will overwrite `another`'s stack frame: the values you passed to it are now sort of "safe". That's why the second call to `printf` outputs the values you expect.

I've heard of people who dislike using the heap so much that they use this "trick" in the following way: they form a stack array in a function and `return` a pointer to it, then, after the function returns, they *copy its contents* to an array in the caller's scope before calling any other function, and then proceed to use it. **Never** do this, for the sake of all the people who may read your code.

Comment: Thank you, this is a brilliant answer to exactly why for me, I run the code I posted and still always get the correct result for int*

Comment: @Mantracker: you're always welcome =)